# behaviour of unification in prolog in presence of arithmetic operators

Tags: prolog, unification

```
12 ?- 3+4*5 = X+Y.
X = 3,
Y = 4*5.

13 ?- 3+4*5 = X*Y.
false.

16 ?- 3*4+5 = X*Y.
false.
```

I was expecting

```
13 ?- 3+4*5 = X*Y.
X = 3+4, Y = 5.

16 ?- 3*4+5 = X*Y.
X = 3, Y = 4+5.
```

Is there some "precedence" problem? I'm using the last swi-prolog release.

Comment: So, you need some predicate to get '3+4' from '3+4*5' or it's just curious question?

Comment: curious question but the predicate to get 3+4 would interesting though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a precedence issue that you need to take into account.

Prolog attaches a numeric precedence value to each operator defined, so that its parse can automatically treat, e.g., 3+4*5 the same as if parentheses had been used to state 3+(4*5).

So your first example worked as expected, but not the second or third.  There was simply no way to unify the terms, so Prolog returned false.

Comment: Got it! I thought since I was using unification that 3+4*5 = X*Y was just a pattern recognition or something but it makes sense.

Comment: @dierre: It is a form of pattern recognition, but a purely syntactic one that runs in linear time. Unification doesn't know about the rules of arithmetic. Adding them completely would not be possible, since arithmetic equality is undecidable in general.

Comment: well, actually I thought it considers arithmetic because it basically evals * before + so the unification of 4*5 happens before 3+4 so Y gets 4*5 but than I have *Y and I can't unify 3+ because I'm missing the *.

Comment: what I'm saying is +(3, *(4,5) ) = *(X,Y) I hope it's clear with prefix notation. That's why it can't unify. But I thought that since in prolog everything is a term, and that I can write X = 4+5 and the output of X would be 4+5 than writing my example would be a simple reading of chars but + is a predicate so that's why I was wrong.

Comment: @dierre: It might be more accurate to say in this context that + and * are functors, ie. that as an expression 3+4*5 gets parsed just as you say as +(3,*(4,5)).  Functors are the building blocks of structures (compound terms) in Prolog, and predicates are a special case of functors that can be invoked (called) as goals.

Comment: @hardmath: I'm sorry. A functor indeed. Man I have the AI final in 2 weeks and I'm still using random words :D

Comment: @dierre: @hardmath's comment is on-the-spot, the expression gets *parsed*. It doesn't get evaluated at all, which is what I meant by stating unification doesn't do arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's something about it

[Each operator have Precedence. the precedence of + is 500, and the precedence of * 400](http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node84.html#subsec.l9.operators.def)